# vhosts not included in apache

Tags: apache, virtualhost, vhosts

I defined some `VirtualHost` in `httpd-vhosts.conf` and in `httpd.conf` I have this line :

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

But my virtual hosts not work !
I think this file not included because I trying to create some errors in `httpd-vhosts.conf` but apache started without any problem.

What should I do ?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Apache?

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes, I trying restart apache with `sudo apachectl restart` and also I restart my system too

Comment: Try apachectl configtest

Comment: @cloud1 return `[Wed Oct 05 12:22:27.029372 2016] [so:warn] [pid 2588] AH01574: module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
Syntax OK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I trying to restore `httpd.conf` and `extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` from `orginal/` folder and reconfigure apache, so problem solved !